# Sharepoint - find all permissions granted to a group

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

Using MOSS 2007 is there any way to see what permissions to what objects/sites have been assigned to a group?  I know it's easy to see what permissions a particular site/webpart has, but can I tell what permissions a group has been granted without checking each and every object with unique permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out the sites and lists that a group has access to:

1. Go to **Site Settings** and click on **People and Groups**.
2. Click on the name of the group in the panel at the top-left corner of the screen.
3. Click **Settings**, **View Group Permissions**.
4. A dialog will appear showing the URLs the group has access to.

Comment: check out my answer regarding the new admin toolkit, it's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of anyway of doing this for groups, but the Access Checker Web Part will do this for individual users if it helps:

http://www.codeplex.com/AccessChecker

Answer (score 1):

The new admin toolkit (version 4.0) has just been released. it contains a solution that when deployed to a site will add a link to site settings page, allowing you to view "effective permissions" for almost everything / everyone in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Big fan of the Access Checker web part.  Nice because it will tell you not only the sites that your user has access to, it will also show you the sites that they specifically don't have access to - which can be helpful when troubleshooting.

One thing to note - the Access Check runs kind of like a job - you enter the person you are checking on and "run it" - it scans the site structure and returns your permissions information.

No experience w/ the new admin toolkit tool referred to above, but can say that, as a general rule, you should have this toolkit installed - it is very helpful - and I suspect that this specific tool works as advertised.